# tar -cf not preserving exact modification time

Tags: tar

When creating a tar archive with `-c`, the modification time seems to be changing, specifically it cuts off the time after the decimal, leaving the modtime to be just the integer value of what it was.

Notice:
```

```
[localhost] $ mkdir test
[localhost] $ stat test
  File: ‘test’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Modify: 2016-07-18 17:01:33.116807520 -0400 # <------ Notice exact time
[localhost] $ tar -cf test.tar test
[localhost] $ tar -xf test.tar
[localhost] $ stat test
  File: ‘test’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Modify: 2016-07-18 17:01:33.000000000 -0400 # <------ Notice how time is rounded
```

(I removed irrelevant parts from output of `stat` for readability)

I've inquired `man tar`, but couldn't find an option that'll preserve *exact* modification time in nanoseconds. Could someone explain why such behavior is occurring? Or is this expected during tar creation.

Update: So far no luck, I tried playing around with `tar` options but most of options that deal with time are related to a files' access time, and not modtime. The ones that do deal with modtime *change* the modtime, which isn't something I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case anyone googling the same issue stumbles upon this thread (like I did):

The solution (at least one of them) is to use the `-H` option, as answered here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397130/tar-how-to-preserve-timestamps-down-to-more-than-a-second-of-precision/397132#397132

The `tar(1)` manpage does not point out the practical implications of the `-H` arguments at all; I think it would be very helpful if a search for a likely keyword (`"nanosecond"`, `"second"`, `"resolution"`, etc.) led to the paragraph on `-H`.